# Convert DNA Sequences into numerical vectors for R / Weka

Tags: dna-sequence

I would like to use machine learning techniques such as Naive Bayes and SVM in Weka to identify species using DNA Sequence data.
The Issue is that I have to convert the DNA sequences into numerical vectors.

MY sequences are like this:

------------------------------------------------G
------------------------------------------GGAGATG
------------------------------------------GGAGATG
------------------------------------------GGAGATG
TTATTAATTCGAGCAGAATTAGGAAATCCTGGATCTTTAATTGGTGATG
----------------------------------------------ATG
CTATTAATTCGAGCTGAGCTAAGCCAGCCCGGGGCTCTGCTCGGAGATG
-----------------------TCAACCTGGGGCCCTACTCGGAGACG
----TAATCCGAGCAGAATTAAGCCAACCTGGCGCCCTACTAGGGGATG
CTATTAATTCGAGCTGAGCTAAGCCAGCCTGGGGCTCTGCTCGGAGATG
TTATTAATTCGTTTTGAGTTAGGCACTGTTGGAGTTTTATTAG---ATA

How can I do this? Any suggestion of other programs for doing ML with DNA sequences besides Weka?

Answer (score 0):

This answer makes use of R.

You can use R's `Biostrings` package for this.

Install package first:

```
source("http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite(c("Biostrings"))
```

Convert character string to DNAstring:

```
dna1 <- DNAString("------------------------------------------------G------------------------------------------GGAGATG")
```

Alternatively,

```
dna2 <- DNAStringSet(c("ACGT", "GTCA", "GCTA"))


alphabetFrequency(dna1)
letterFrequency(dna1, "GC")
....
```

Then (if you must) you can call Weka functions from R, e.g. Naive Bayes with `NB <- make_Weka_classifier("weka/classifiers/bayes/NaiveBayes")
; NB(colx ~ . , data=mydata)`, or convert your data as you wish and/or export to other types of files that Weka understands. The `foreign::write.arff()` function comes to mind. But I  wouldn't use Weka for this.

Needless to say, you can simply also enter these sequences into a [website performing a BLAST search](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PROGRAM=blastn&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&LINK_LOC=blasthome) and get likely species candidates.

For `CTATTAATTCGAGCTGAGCTAAGCCAGCCCGGGGCTCTGCTCGGAGATG` I get mitochondrial DNA from "banded rock lizard" (*Petrosaurus mearnsi*) with 91% probability.